# I cant connect to unity services

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to connect to unity services, and it says this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBE0X.png]

I try to link it to a new project id, but it connects for a split second and comes back to this.

Comment: do you have Unit Hub installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to logout then login again from Unity Hub

Comment: i tried that, it does nothing

Comment: Did you logout and login with your Unity ID? Did you try the buttons "Refresh access" and "New link.." in the screenshot?